# Fill screen with ImageView on tap

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, lightbox

I have a `ListView` in my application that has both text and images in it on each row. Now, when the row is clicked I'd like to zoom the image to fill the screen. On the next click it should collapse to it's original size.

What I'm looking for is something similar to [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). When the image is clicked it expands.

I have access to the ImageView. What do I need to do to it to achieve this kind of effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to zoom in/out view you can use scale animation. I recommend to watch Chet Haase tutorials called DevBytes: [View Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=_UWXqFBF86U#t=54s)